# how to set session in codeigniter and access it inside methods?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to set session in my controller and access the session data inside the methods.  Can anyone tell me a way to implement this? and below is my code block

```
if ($data['result'] = $this->Webmanager_model->admin_login($credential)) {
    foreach ($data['result'] as $val) {
        $credentials = array(
            'adminid' => $val->admin_id,
            'name' => $val->name,
            'username' => $val->username);
    }
    $this->session->adminid = $val->admin_id;
    $this->session->name = $val->name;
    $this->session->username = $val->username;
    $this->load->view('dashboard1');
} else {
    echo "access denied";
}
```

this way iam set session but it shows null on the next method.

Comment: To set : $this->session-> set_userdata("adminid","your value"); 
To Access : $this->session-> userdata("adminid");

Comment: ok let me try this

Comment: Is codeigniter still relevant these days? Great!

Comment: @undefined You not use CodeIgniter, doesn't mean that it is not relevant

Comment: but now itself showing null results

Comment: your way of setting session parameters should work ... take a look @your autoload.php (in your application/config/ folder) there is a line `$autoload['libraries'] = array(...);` In this Array you should have set the value `session` - is this the case on your site ? something like `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session',...);`

Comment: this are already set but session data is not accessible on method course

Comment: use `echo $this->session->user_data('adminid');` in your method course

Comment: in method course it shows null

Answer (score 0):

```
if($data['result'] = $this->Webmanager_model->admin_login($credential))
{
foreach ($data['result'] as $val) 
{
 $credentials=array('adminid'=>$val->admin_id,
 'name'=>$val->name,
 'username'=>$val->username);
}
// Set Session
$this->session->set_userdata("login_detail",$credentials);
$this->load->view('dashboard1');
} else {
echo "access denied";
}
// Get session;
$sessionArray=$this->session->userdata("login_detail");
```

Comment: i want the admin id inside the method course, how to access?

Comment: array(1) { ["__ci_last_regenerate"]=> int(1534404730) } this error showing when iam accessing in method course using $sessionArray=$this->session->userdata();

Comment: I found that the issue is with some earlier version of Codeigniter 3 and this is a bug already reported in their website.The underlying session bug has been fixed on: 
    3.1.2, 3.1.3, 3.1.4